# TS: Creating a mapped type from the keys of a dynamic object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, reduce

I realise that `.reduce` is quite difficult to type in TS, and what I'm attempting may not be possible. But anyway, I'd like some advice on how best to type the following:

Let's say I have an Array of `people`:

```
  const people = [
    { id: '1' },
    { id: '2' },
    { id: '3' },
  ]
```

I'm making a form with `Formik` so that you can enter a name for these people. I'd like the `values` of that form to be structured as something like `values.1.name` where `1` is the `id` of that person.

```
  const initialValues = people.reduce((acc, p) => ({
    ...acc,
    [p.id]: {
      name: '',
    },
  }), {});
```

When using the form, ideally I want `Values` to be typed as something like this:

```
  interface Values {
    [key: '1' | '2' | '3']: string;
  }
```

The problem is that by default, `.reduce` will type my `initialValues` and end up typed as `{}`, so trying to access `values[person.id]` will result in an error.

I saw that you can do this:

```
const peopleIds = {
    one: true,
    two: true,
    three: true,
  };

  type PeopleIds = keyof typeof peopleIds;
```

This could be very useful if my list of `people` was always going to be static. Essentially I want `Values` to be typed as an object where the possible keys are all the `people.id` values.

Understandably, it's a little complex, but I'm wondering if this is even doable in TS as I will rely on things like `.reduce` in order to generate my form's schema and all that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the type as long as you keep track of the literal values inside the `id` properties of the elements of the `people` array.  The easiest way to do that is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const people = [
    { id: '1' },
    { id: '2' },
    { id: '3' },
] as const;
```

Then the type you're looking for is

```
type InitValueType = Record<typeof people[number]['id'], { name: string }>;
/* type InitValueType = {
    1: {
        name: string;
    };
    2: {
        name: string;
    };
    3: {
        name: string;
    };
} */
```

And it's easy enough to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to get the output of `reduce()` to be what you want:

```
const initialValues = people.reduce((acc, p) => ({
    ...acc,
    [p.id]: {
        name: '',
    },
}), {} as InitValueType);
```

That type assertion isn't completely type safe; it doesn't stop some bad things from happening:

```
const badInitialValues = people.reduce((acc, p) => ({
    ...acc,
    [p.id]: {
        kablam: '', // what?
    },
}), {} as InitValueType);
```

But it might be the best you can reasonably do here, since trying to give a typing for `reduce()` that represents the single callback as representing each link in a chain of types that starts with `{}` and culminates in `InitValueType` would be incredibly messy and unlikely to ultimately buy you more safety.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUxHANgmBeGBtAUDAmAbxgEsATALhgHIBGGmAXwBp9CSLqaAmR19gU5VaAZn5sAujACGEGKEhRcuKAE9EMAJJhSUAGoyUAVwQAVDeiwAlBKABO5ADzrEIAGbwkqBNjDGAWwAjBHtJbBoKGkkWYhgwGQCEamh7UjAAc2YAPgBuXAB6ACoYV3QdPUMTc0tMYkEYOmoiBsJ4xOSYVPSM-LamPsIeZtbCBKSUqDTMwYIBhtERtrbxzu6ZhvmmGCKClUVoMl0oUiMq03ksNx8AOnsEcmNgBAAKF5lgYFi4AEpMbJgLxabRuoI+Xwa2DgNwokiWywIq24NDY-TYTB+sSI2zk2mO5xqiB++VwB1gQRk5AqJzORgudWuaDuDyer3en2+fwwAKBDVBN3BqMIUJh5Dh9QRBAA1jIgihEsjYgUCjAAO4ACxkUAA-Jt0ZjiDj5NSCRYifkgA)